# how to write an individual error_log for each file

Tags: php

How can I set up a distinct separate error_log for each file?

I tried putting the following line in an include that goes in all files but didn't seem to work.

```
ini_set('error_log ', str_replace('.php', '', __FILE__));
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: It works. But of course `__FILE__` is a magic constant that represents **current file**, not some other file that tops the stack trace.

Comment: Further, "each file" is ambiguous.  Do you truly mean each file? What if a file includes other file(s) - where should the included file(s) log(s) be written?  This could turn into a ton of different files, depending on the size of the application.

Comment: From the manual - *__FILE__ The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. **If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.***

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs It can be a cool prank assignment for interns: search the project tree for log files.

Comment: Oh, silly me, for some reason I forgot about that. Better put that in each file.

Comment: I move that line the one file and tested, but the error are still going to the folder's error_log.

Comment: It worked now, as you can see in that line, there's a space after error_log inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by declaring a new var before the include with the `__FILE__` value.

```
$errorFileName = __FILE__;
include 'headers.php';
```

and inside the headers.php I check if that variable is set then use it to set the error_log.

```
if (isset($errorFileName)) {
  ini_set('error_log', str_replace('.php', '', $errorFileName));
}
```